# Visual Studio 2012 not showing Crystal Report Viewer in Toolbox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I have **windows form Application** and want to generate Crystal reports. I have downloaded Crystal report(64bit) of SAP and Installed,but I can't add crystal report viewer because I can't see "**Crystal report viewer and crystal report Document**"

I Confirmed that In project Properties window in the Application tab,I have **Target framework 4.5** selected.

I also confirmed that SAP crystal report 64bit successfully installed on my computer.

Problem is:

```
 I can't view "Crystal report viewer and Crystal Report Document" in Toolbox.
```

How can i get ride of this?

Comment: have you installed the crystal report for visual studio (CRforVS i.e a developer version) or just run-time environment version?

Comment: I Installed CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_10

Answer (score 2):

you should install this one from given 
[Crystal Reports Download Link](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)[image]

You have installed just only run-time version which is needed by the client system, just to run crystal report.
This one is Developer Version... And solves your problem.

Comment: have you found your solution?